# what could be the possible risk if we are using the machine instruction and accessing directly the hardware

Tags: compiler-construction

what could be the possible risk if I use the machine instruction and accessing directly the hardware. it will help me more if explain the Access Violation and Buffer Overflow in this context?.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Can you provide same code?

Answer (score 0):

When you write an assembly program (which is heavier than a high-level-programming), it will be runned in **User Mode** - like every other .exe application. Applications can only access their own segment in ram and a few CPU registers and some pointers directly. If an application wants to output or input something, it has to use system functions (API) - even if they are written in assembly.
The risk of buffer overflow exists, if you take not good care of the data model, but you can set certain segments of your program to be unexecutable or unwriteable, so the danger of buffer-overflow-injections won't exist.
The only programs, that are able to access the hole hardware directly are **kernelmode drivers** (.sys files). A runtime error in a Kernelmode driver can cause a **bluescreen**. Therefore, programmers write only Kernelmode drivers for those things that can't be done otherwise. Writing Kernelmode drivers is rarely done by mainstream programmers.